# Returning JSON from an Ajax GET call - receiving an Undefined error on all but the first record in the JSON object

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json

Here's my client side code:

```
$.ajax({
                url: 'http://localhost/App.WebAPI/api/Messages/AppName',
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                crossDomain: true,
                success: function (data) {
                    WriteResponse(data);
                },
                error: function (x, y, z) {
                    alert(x + '\n' + y + '\n' + z);
                }
            });

function WriteResponse(messages) {
            var strResult = "<table><th>AppId</th><th>Message</th>";
            $.each(messages, function (index, message) {
                strResult += "<tr><td>" + message.AppId + "</td><td> " + message.Message + "</td></tr>";
            });
            strResult += "</table>";
            $("#divResult").html(strResult);
        }
```

The URL in the Ajax call returns 3 records, but when they are output to the browser via "WriteResponse", here's what I get (blurred out to protect company information):

[image]

Is my .each method not formed correctly?  I am not an expert in jQuery, so I wouldn't be surprised if I goofed up something simple.  Notice that it does see all 3 records but it outputs "Undefined" in the 2nd and 3rd records... any ideas why??

Comment: Show us your response.

Comment: LOL @SLaks I figured it out - once you said to show my response, that triggered me to look at the output, and it was because I had some foreign key relationships in my database that was messing with the JSON output - it made it look all funky, and that was why the "undefined" error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I had a foreign key relationship defined in my table (MSSQL) - I am using Entity Framework - and so when the JSON was returned by the WebAPI, the foreign key was included in the JSON, as expected, but for some reason it made the JSON look all funky.  I removed all relationships in my table, ran the API call again, and now I am getting all my records back.

But I know that just works around the issue of having foreign keys, which I will investigate further.