# jQuery find() give undefined on jQuery.ajax response data instead of table element

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I trying to fetch data from query via ajax call. When I write console.log(data) which give full page html. But when I try jQuery(data).find('table') gives undefined in console.

Following code which I have tried:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js" type = "text/javascript"></script>
<script>
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery.ajaxPrefilter( "json script", function( options ) {
            options.crossDomain = true;
        });
    jQuery("#searchbtn").click(function(){
        var url = 
        jQuery.ajax({
            dataType: "html",
            url: "http://cors.io/?u=http://www.netmeds.com/searchdrug?keyword=albuterol&product=All%20Drugs",
            success: function( data ) {
                //var html = jQuery(data);
                var req_table = jQuery(data).find('table');
                console.log(data);  // works good
                console.log("req_table : "+req_table); // not working
        }
    });
    });

});
</script>
</head>
<body>
<input type = "text" name="product" id = "product"/>
<input type = "button" name ="btn" value ="Search" id = "searchbtn"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What does console.log(data); logs in console?

Comment: i didn't find any table node in the html of your response

Comment: @AmitSingh it gives full html page source in cosole.

Comment: Could you simulate this on a fiddle?

Comment: No wonder you couldn't find table. http://jsfiddle.net/msbsoqdw/

Comment: you will get table if avoid third party `http://cors.io/?u=` but you will get problem of persmissions

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20842145/returning-json-from-an-ajax-get-call-receiving-an-undefined-error-on-all-but-t     ,,, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31247234/ajax-data-returns-page-source-code-or-undefined      follow this links,may be help full....